# axios mock can't handle default headers when using jest

Tags: vue.js, mocking, jestjs, vuex

I'm making a test that includes an axios call to an endpoints. I want to mock out the call to the endpoint and return some custom data so that I'm not hitting a server everytime I'm testing.

Here is the code for the action that is in it's own action.js file.

```
login ({commit}, user)  {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post('https://backendauth.free.beeceptor.com/api/login', user)
     .then(resp => {
       console.log('response here')
       console.log(resp)
       console.log(resp.data)
       const token = resp.data.success.token
       const user = resp.data.user
       localStorage.setItem('token', token)
       axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
       commit('LOGIN_SUCCESS', token, user)
```

When logging in the action calls out to an endpoint and that endpoint returns a token which is stored in local storage. The token is also appended to the axios default headers so I don't have to attach the token everytime I want to make an axios call in the application.

Now to the test. I've written a test that sucessfully mocks the axios post however fails with an error when setting the default headers for the mock.

Here is the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined

  37 |           const user = resp.data.user
  38 |           localStorage.setItem('token', token)
> 39 |           axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
     |                          ^
  40 |           commit('LOGIN_SUCCESS', token, user)
  41 |           resolve(resp)
  42 |         })
```

Here is the test including the mock

```
    import actions from "../../src/store/actions";

let url = "";
let body = "";

jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  post: (_url, _body, config) => { 
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve({'data' : {'success': {'token' : 'test'}}})
    })
  },


}))


describe('login action', () => {
    it("let the user login and access login success mutator", async() => {
        const commit = jest.fn()
        const username = 'test'
        const password = 'test'

        await actions.login({commit}, {username, password})
    })
})
```

The jest mock is a full mock which returns a promise when called, with the data I need, however the code fails when trying to set the headers.  Is there a way I can mock this out as well or do I need to write the mock in a different way?

Comment: Found a solution to this problem by using a package called axios-mock-adapter which can be found here https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter. This mocks axios using a mock adapter and allows the headers to be set. I then just test if the header exists on the axios object

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you do it for anyone with the same problem. Npm install axios-mock-adapter and then use the following code but change it for your needs.

```
import actions from "../../src/store/actions";
import axios from 'axios';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
describe('login action', () => {
    it("let the user login and access login success mutator", async() => {


        let mockAdapter = new MockAdapter(axios);

        mockAdapter.onPost('https://hotel-dev.devtropolis.co.uk/api/apilogin').reply(200, {
              token: 'test token',
              user: {username: 'test', password: 'test'}
          });


        const commit = jest.fn()
        const username = 'test'
        const password = 'test'

        await actions.login({commit}, {username, password})

    expect(axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization).toBe('Bearer test token')

    expect(commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      "LOGIN_SUCCESS",'test token', {username, password})
    })

})
```